# Matlab: 0 < NaN = 0

Tags: matlab, nan

I've been really tripped out by this error.

Is this really expected from MATLAB or is it a bug?

Why wouldn't 0 < NaN produce an error?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have also just tested this within Java where 0<Float.NaN = false. It's the same result. Anyway, Matlab is based on Java. Also, I found this [Secure computing cert: Don't compare with NaN](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM07-J.+Do+not+attempt+comparisons+with+NaN) which says don't compare with NaN !          This feels like a noob mistake although I've been programming for 10+ years.

Comment: MATLAB certainly uses Java for UIs and other purposes - but just to be clear, the core numeric algorithms in MATLAB are all based on either C++ code, or standard numeric libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [MathWorks' documentation on NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html), the only logical operator that does not return `false` with `NaN` is `~=` (not equals).

This makes sense logically, though: if something is "not a number", it cannot (should not) be compared to numbers. `NaN` doesn't equal anything.

Further, this is an IEEE standard: `NaN` is unordered and thusly cannot be compared. It doesn't work in any IEEE 754-compliant language.

In short, it's not a bug.

Comment: Why do you say that "the only well-defined logical operator on `NaN` is `~=`"? The documentation states that _logical operations involving `NaN`s always return `false`, except `~=`_. So both `==` and `~=` are well-defined on `NaN`

Comment: @LuisMendo Edited my poor word choice.

Comment: +1 now. Still, I wouldn't say "Hence you cannot use any comparison operators with NaN". You _can_. You only need to understand the result, which can be phrased as "a `NaN` doesn't equal anything"

Answer (score 8):

NaN has special properties.  Math operations performed with NaN result in a NaN  (x+NaN = NaN).  Comparisons to a NaN return false.

http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2009/02/04/how-do-i-test-for-nan-in-my-model/